# Sequelize umzug migrations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, umzug

I am using `sequelize js` and developed a `node js application`, which is deployed to production and have live DB.

while in development mode, if I need to `alter` the `DB`, I used to do it using **`Sequelize.sync({ force: true })`** and it worked well.

But now, after development is done **I want to alter a table and add a column to it.**

**I searched many posts but, didn't get an exact example on how to run these migrations.**

I tried to use `Umzug` and run a migration, but it is throwing me errors.

Here is the code I tried,

**migrations/barmigration.js:**

```
  var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

"use strict";

module.exports = {

    up: function(migration, DataTypes) {
      return [
      migration.addColumn(
        'Bars',
        'PrinterId',
        Sequelize.STRING
      ),
      migration.addColumn(
        'Bars',
        'PrinterStatus',
        Sequelize.STRING
      )]

    },

    down: function(migration, DataTypes) {
        return
         [
            migration.removeColumn('Bars', 'PrinterStatus'),
            migration.removeColumn('Bars', 'PrinterId')
        ]
    }

};
```

Here is the **`umzug configuration`:**

```
 var Umzug = require('umzug');
    var sequelize = require('sequelize');

    var umzug = new Umzug({

        // storage: 'sequelize',
        model: 'Bar',


        storageOptions: {
            sequelize: sequelize,
        },

        migrations: {
            path: './migrations',
            pattern: /\.js$/
        }

    });

    //  umzug.up().then(function(migrations)  {
    //    console.log('Migration complete!');
   //     });

    umzug.down().then(function(migrations)  {
      console.log('Migration complete!');
    });
```

When I run that file, I am getting an error in `up function`, at this position **`return migration.addColumn`**

**Error:**

**`Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'addColumn' of undefined`**

So, the parameter migration seems to be `undefined`. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to define the `params` property inside `migrations` attribute of the object passed to the constructor of `Umzug` - it defines the parameters that are passed to the `up` and `down` functions. I suppose that the configuration object should be as follows

```
{
    storage: 'sequelize',
    storageOptions: {
        sequelize: sequelize // here should be a sequelize instance, not the Sequelize module
    },
    migrations: {
        params: [
            sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
            Sequelize // Sequelize constructor - the required module
        ],
        path: './migrations',
        pattern: /\.js$/
    }
}
```

With above definition the `migration` parameter would now become the `sequelize.getQueryInterface()`, so simply `queryInterface`, and the `DataTypes` parameter is the `Sequelize` itself.

The `model` attribute is used to define a Sequelize migrations model, you do not need to define it if you are satisfied with the default `SequelizeMeta` table creation. [Here](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug#configuration) is how the `Umzug` constructor object should look like, and [here](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug#sequelize) is how the `storageOptions` can look like.

**EDIT**

In separate file you need to create a Sequelize instance (further used to define models etc.) and export it. Let's assume files tree as below

```
 - db
     - database.js
     - umzug.js
```

So in the `database.js` we create a Sequelize instance and export it.

```
 // database.js
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

 const db = {
     sequelize: new Sequelize(connectionString, options),
     Sequelize: Sequelize
 };

 module.exports = db;
```

Then, in the `Umzug` configuration file

```
// umzug.js
const db = require('./database');

// here comes the configuration and initialization of Umzug instance with use of db object
// db.sequelize -> sequelize instance
// db.Sequelize -> sequelize constructor (class)
```

Comment: thnx for your response. but I am getting error, `TypeError: sequelize.getQueryInterface is not a function`. I required `sequelize` in the file.

Comment: `sequelize.getQueryInterface` must be run on Sequelize instance, not on the constructor itself. Did you create a sequelize instance in separate file and required it in this one?

Comment: yes, I have an instance of `sequelize` and exported that instance.

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong. You would have to update the question with your new code version.

Comment: I have edited the answer, maybe now it will help you.

Comment: thnx for your update, now I got my migration working. but not completely. When I call `up()` method it is working fine. but, when I call `down()`, strangely it is not working. updated my latest code in the question.

Comment: Not working in what way? What happens when you call `down()`?

Comment: the migration method gets called, but `drop query` is not getting called.

Comment: I have tested above configuration and everything works fine, source of the problem with not removing columns must be somewhere else...

Comment: thank you. It worked now and strangely I didn't change any code.